# Reading XML from URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am writing code to retrieve some part of an xml document. I am using Wolfram API (I am registered and I have an AppID.). So if I save the xml file locally after I execute the search command (variable "url" below),it works perfecly (if I have xmlDoc.load("query2.xml") where the xml is savedd in query2.url). However, I want to put a url instead, and get them on the fly rather than save the xml. I tried xmlDoc.load(url) but that didn't work, and after researching I found a function that's supposed to help retrieve this xml data from a tutorial website, but that didn't work either (it doesnt display anything on the page). How can I get the xml given a url?

Thanks in advance!

```
<body>
<div id="container" style="background-color:yellow"></div>

<script>


//load xml file

var url = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=distance%20from%20london%20to%20california&appid=xxx";
if (window.ActiveXObject){
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false; //Enforce download of XML file first. IE only.
}
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
var xmlDoc= document.implementation.createDocument("","doc",null);
if (typeof xmlDoc!="undefined") {


function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
} 
xmlDoc.load(loadXMLDoc(url));

//xmlDoc.load("query2.xml");

}
else {

}

//Regular expression used to match any non-whitespace character
var notWhitespace = /\S/

function getnumber(){
//Cache "messages" element of xml file
var msgobj=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("plaintext")[1]

//REMOVE white spaces in XML file. Intended mainly for NS6/Mozilla
for (i=0;i<msgobj.childNodes.length;i++){
if ((msgobj.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3)&&
(!notWhitespace.test(msgobj.childNodes[i].nodeValue))) {
// that is, if it's a whitespace text node
msgobj.removeChild(msgobj.childNodes[i])
i--
}
}

//Get answer and display it in DIV:
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("plaintext")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue
}

if (typeof xmlDoc!="undefined"){
if (window.ActiveXObject) //if IE, simply execute script (due to async prop).
getdaily()
else //else if NS6, execute script when XML object has loaded
xmlDoc.onload=getnumber
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you try var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhttp.open('GET', url, false);?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.open('GET', url, false);
xhttp.send();

xmlDoc.load(xhttp.responseXML);

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can someone help please? ...

Comment: can you post one fiddle of the code?

Comment: The API url http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=distance%20from%20london%20to%20california&appid=xxx don't return response [<msg>Invalid appid</msg>]

Comment: @martinezjc What do you mean? I've posted all my code
I removed the return statement and it still doesnt work. The page takes a while to load, which means it must be processing the url, but nothing appears on the screen.. :S

Comment: It returned false because I have "xxx" instead of my AppID, which I hid. O/w, it gives all the info. I've saved the file locally and it works perfectly so, I'm only having trouble loading from url